# column name parsing issue in dataframe transpose

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, parsing

I have the following dataframe:

```
+-------+----------+---------+-------+
|ac.inc |b.corp    |cdi.ltd  |d.corp |
+-------+----------+---------+-------+
|1      |2         |3        |    4  |
+-------+----------+---------+-------+
```

and I want to get the following output:

```
+----------+---------+
|company   |value    |
+----------+---------+
|ac.inc    |1        | 
|b.corp    |2        | 
|cdi.ltd   |3        | 
|d.corp    |4        | 
+----------+---------+
```

I am using the  following code to transpose it, but the trouble here is executing the code on the parsing part. As the names have a dot in them, parsing is a bit hard. The following code executes fine if I remove the dot in the names (acinc  |bcorp    |cdiltd    |dbros)

```
df.select(map(df.columns.flatMap(cnames => Seq(lit(cnames),col(cnames))):_*).as("map"))
  .select(explode($"map"))
```

Any help how to fix this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that in spark, when you refer to `ac.inc`, spark tries to find field `inc` in the struct column `ac`, which does not exist in your dataframe. To tell spark not to interpret the dot, you can enclose the column name with backticks.

```scala
df.select(map(df.columns.flatMap(cnames => Seq(lit(cnames), col(s"`$cnames`"))) :_*).as("map"))
  .select(explode($"map"))
  .show
```

```
+-------+-----+
|    key|value|
+-------+-----+
| ac.inc|    1|
| b.corp|    2|
|cdi.ltd|    3|
| d.corp|    4|
+-------+-----+
```